# Inadvertently Stacking While Loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, ros

I've got a program right now that is meant to display an image, and allow for various functions on keypress (e.g., load a new frame, crop a region of interest, etc). It's also set up so that if too much time passes with no action, it'll automatically attempt to load a new image.

```
def triggeredbytimer():
    global f, x1i, y1i, x2i, y2i, sid, keepgoing
    keepgoing = False
    print "Inactivity has lead to an automatic refresh. Loading newest image."
    f = 0; t = 0
    incoming = imagerequest(sid, f, t, x1i, y1i, x2i, y2i)
    imagecallback(incoming)

def imagecallback(data):
    print "----------------------- imagecallback"
    global sid, f, x1i, y1i, x2i, y2i, img, refPt, cropping, keepgoing
    keepgoing = True
    ########### \\// change this to change wait for autorefresh
    tmr = Timer(10.0, triggeredbytimer)
    tmr.start()
    ##################################
    b = data.b; t = data.tr; sid = data.sid; error = int(data.error)
    t = float(t); sid = int(sid)
    expandedt = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(t)) 
    print str(t) + " ----> " + expandedt
    print "----------------------- image incoming"
    timestr = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(t))
    print "Loaded image from %s."%timestr
    imagedata = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(b, "bgr8")
    npimg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', imagedata)
    cv2.imwrite('temp_image_np.jpg', imagedata)
    img = cv2.imread('temp_image_np.jpg')
    clone = img.copy()
    cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.setMouseCallback("image", mouseclickcb)
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    while keepgoing == True:
        key = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
        ## (here there are a lot of keypress functions, for brevity I included only one)
        elif key == ord("t"):
            print "Looking for newest frame..."
            tmr.cancel()
            t = 0; f = 0
            incoming = imagerequest(sid, f, t, x1i, y1i, x2i, y2i)
            imagecallback(incoming)
```

(**NOTE**: The images are fetched from a ROS program via services, and that is where the "imagerequest" function comes from. All of that works fine: the problem is specifically as prescribed.)

To summarize here- since there's a bit of irrelevant clippings in this snippet - an image is loaded by imagecallback. When that function is called, a timer starts (time limit is arbitrary, set low here for testing). When the timer expires, triggeredbytime() requests a new image. It acquires the image via a ROS service, then takes the return from that and uses it as an input to imagecallback(data), thus loading the image and allowing all the keypress functions to still be valid.

So the problem is that whenever the program refreshes with a new frame, the while keepgoing == True loop does not stop, leading to stacked loops that go on and get worse with every refresh. this leads to a single keypress executing multiple times, which quickly overwhelms the program it's pulling images from. (Originally, this was just a while True: loop, but I added the "keepgoing" variable to try to remedy the situation - unsuccessfully, as it were.) I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, and attempting to turn the loop "off" long enough to kill the first loop but allowing the next one to execute has not worked out so far.  Is there any way to exit this while keepgoing == True loop cleanly to prevent things from stacking as such, or is there a better way in general to address the problem of loading a new image after a certain amount of time?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: to be clear, the problem is with ending the 'while' loop when the timer hits 0. setting keepgoing = False doesn't seem to work (probably because I can't 'return' it), so I need something similar to that if it's possible...

Comment: You could add a second argument to imagecallback that tells it how long or how many times it should run before setting keepgoing to false.

Comment: But would that work if I want it to run indefinitely until the timer is up or a key is pressed?

Comment: So you want it to run continuously until an event happens, but you don't want it to run too often?

Same solution, just add the variable and have it wait x amount of times so that the loop executes every nth loop.  Better way is to just have it sleep for an arbitrary amount of time and then execute, or break if an event happens.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow with how to make it run the way you describe. Replace while with for(in range), and have the variable iterated over reset itself before it hits the end?

Comment: Add a second argument for imagecallback(data, x) and under the while loop add: if count <= x: time.sleep(y) count -= 1 (or any other value).  
That way it only runs every x attempts which should prevent the ROS program from getting overwhelmed with requests

Comment: I'll give it a try. thanks!

Comment: So upon further thought this doesn't really address the problem. I'll edit the original description to make it more clear, but it isn't about keeping the ROS server from being overwhelmed - it's about ending the 'while' loop when the timer hits 0. Otherwise I'll still have the same problem, it'll just be more organized...